# How to remove commas and spaces when submitting a excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to save data that is in an excel file to my database and I would like to check if any of those has a comma or spaces in it and if it does I would like to remove it.

I'm using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet and laravel and if possible I would like to use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet if it can do it.

Here is my code

```
$xl = IOFactory::load($path);

$sheet = $xl->getSheetByName('Products');

$c = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$r = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();

$data = $sheet->rangeToArray("A1:{$c}{$r}", null, false);
$headers = array_shift($data);
$projects = [];

foreach ($data as $row) {

    $entry = array_combine($headers, $row);

    $projects[] = [
        'name' => $entry['Name'],
        'description' => $entry['description'],
        'price' => $entry['price'],
    ];

}

return $projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a function :

```
function cleanData($data) {
 $data= str_replace( ',', '', $data);
  $data= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data);
  return $data;
   }
```

and use it:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {

$entry = array_combine($headers, $row);

$projects[] = [
    'name' => cleanData($entry['Name']),
    'description' => cleanData($entry['description'],
    'price' => cleanData($entry['price']),
];
```

}